# How to return the value of a function variable

Tags: javascript

I'm finishing a carousel and I want to separate the codes.
I need to return the value of a function variable and I don't understand. When I put a value in 'return', it returns, but the value of the variable does not.
I'll just post more important parts of the code and try to explain

This is the first function, which changes images. The function I'm calling is to return the position of the button within the array. This array is the 'buttons' variable.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-button');
function moveSlider() {
  buttons.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        var buttonId;
        var carouselId;
        var btnPosition

        var id = event.target.id;
        buttonPosition(id)
        console.log(buttonPosition())
...
```

The Function I'm calling up there

```
function buttonPosition(id){
  var position;
  for($i = 0; $i < buttons.length; $i++){
      if(id == buttons[$i].id){
          position = $i;
      }
  }

  return position;
}
```

Why does the variable value return 'undefined'?

Comment: Most likely because your `if` condition is never `true` and so you never enter into the branch and set the `position` variable. The only way we can know for sure is if you post all the relevant code so that we can execute your code. Also, it's rather uncommon to use `$` as a prefix to standard variables. `$` is typically used to denote that the variable holds a reference to a custom library object, like a JQuery wrapped set.

Comment: Call to your buttonPosition function in your console.log doesn't have any parameters, therefore id is undefined and if is never true, and position doesn't get assigned therefore you get undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much! Lack of attention kkkk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are first calling the method with the parameter "id". But when you you use console.log your calling the method again but without the parameter.
You should store the returned value of the function in a variable and then work with the or for example output the variable.

```
var yourReturnValue = buttonPosition(id)
console.log(yourReturnValue)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Lack of attention kkkk